# How do I blast a local query against a local database in python/biopython?

Tags: python, biopython, blast, jquery-ui-selectmenu

First of all, I want to come clean that I am a super beginner in programming.
I have 2 zip files (containing one database each) and 4 fasta files (three containing a protein sequence each and one contains a nucleotide sequence).

I would like to create a program that the user can select from a menu either to run an amino acid or a nucleotide file against its database respectively. The code mentioned below was the best that I was able to do. Unfortunately, it doesn't run at all. I will be very obligated if you could direct me on how to handle it?

```
import sys 
import zipfile

def main():
def menu():

print("*****MAIN MENU*****")`

print()

choice = input("""
                  A: For nucleotide "DNA" quest 
                  B: For amino acid "Protein" quest 
                  Q: For Exit the program
                  Please enter your choice: """)

if choice == "A" or choice =="a":
    Dnaquery()

elif choice == "B" or choice =="b":
    Proteinquery()

elif choice=="Q" or choice=="q":
    sys.exit
else:
    print("You must only select either A,B,or Q.")
    print("Please try again")
    menu()

    def Dnaquery(): #for nucletide query
       with zipfile.ZipFile("Dna.zip","r") as zip_ref:
          zip_ref.extractall("C:\Users\Gpapa\Desktop\Zipfiles\DnaDatabase>")

       from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
       fasta_string = open("Dna.fasta").read()
       result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", fasta_string)

   def Proteinquery(): #for protein query
   with zipfile.ZipFile("Protein.zip","r") as zip_ref:
             zip_ref.extractall("C:\Users\Gpapa\Desktop\Zipfiles\ProteinDatabase>")
    def menu2 ()
    print("************Select Protein 2 blast **************")

    print()

     choice = input("""
                  1: For Protein Query 1
                  2: For Protein Query 2
                  3: For Protein Query 3
                  Please enter your choice: """)

     if choice == 1:
      from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
      fasta_string = open("protein1.fasta").read()
       result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp", "prot", fasta_string)

     elif choice == 2:
     from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
      fasta_string = open("protein2.fasta").read()
      result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp", "prot", fasta_string)
      elif choice==3:
      from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
      fasta_string = open("protein3.fasta").read()
      result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp", "prot", fasta_string)
      else:
       print("You must only select either 1,2,or 3")
       print("Please try again")
    menu2()

    main()
```

Comment: Hello @KGee, 

I guess there has been some troube during the copy pasting of your code here, the indentation seems quite wrong. 

Can you also add, what should be the output, and what is the current one? 

As we don't have your files we will not be able to test locally. 

Have a lovely day.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are BLASTing NCBI, not a local BLAST.  I suggest you start here for a local BLAST:

https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=Download